# Как сохранить массив в базу данных android.room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

У меня есть дата-класс, который необходимо сохранить в базе данных room'а:

```
@Entity(tableName = "day_data_table")
data class Day(var subjcts : Iterable<Subject>, var dayOfMonth : String) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

    @ColumnInfo(name = "day_date")
    var Date : String = dayOfMonth
        private set

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_subjects")
    var Subjects : Iterable<Subject> = subjcts
        private set
}
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно сохранить массив с неопределенным заранее количеством элементов,
как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Это должно вам подсказать направление в поиске решения. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986626/android-room-database-how-to-handle-arraylist-in-an-entity

Comment: Вообще сохранять массивы данных в одну запись базы данных не очень правильное решение с точки зрения архитектуры баз данных. На самом деле это совсем неправильное решение, есть же отношения один ко многим и многие ко многим, но кого волнуют такие мелочи, как дисциплины СУБД в наше время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейшее решение это сериализация массива в строку и обратно в массив. Так можно делать если вы не собираетесь менять эти данные, например добавлять или удалять элементы. Для этого создается TypeConverter в удобном вам месте. Вот пример класса, который вы сможете расширять в дальнейшем.

Только замените Iterable на List или другую реализацию.

```kotlin
class TypeConverter {

    private val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun subjctsToJson(subjcts: List<Subject>?): String? {
        return if (subjcts == null || subjcts.isEmpty()) {
            null
        } else {
            gson.toJson(subjcts)
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToSubject(json: String?): List<Subject> {
        return if (json.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            listOf()
        } else {
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<Subject>>() {}.type
            gson.fromJson(json, type)
        }
    }
```

Заметьте, что вам не нужно ничего вызывать room сам найден аннотации @TypeConverter.

Теперь всегда, когда получаете "Cannot figure out how to save this field into database", вы можете прибегнуть к подобному решению.